# Detecting runtime error shortest path finder using dictionary using breadth first search PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I have an undirected graph represented in a dictionary with no edges labels or weights .... just edges .
I used the breadth fears search to get shortest path but always i get a runtime error .
However the code runes correctly on the given test cases .
Here is my complete code :

```
#Using breadth first search
def bfs_paths(graph, start, goal):
    queue = [(start, [start])]
    while queue:
        (vertex, path) = queue.pop(0)

        for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):
            if next == goal:
            yield path + [next]
        else:
            queue.append((next, path + [next]))
def shortest_path(graph, start, goal):
    try:
        return next(bfs_paths(graph, start, goal))
    except StopIteration:
        return None

counter = int(input())
for i in range(counter) :
    N , M = input().strip().split()
    N , M = [int(N),int(M)]
    conn = input().strip().split()
# initialize the graph with dictionary .
    graph ={x : set() for x in range(N) if conn[x-1] != '1'}
    for cell_conn in range(M) :
        cell_0 ,cell_1= input().strip().split()
        cell_0 ,cell_1=[int(cell_0) ,int(cell_1)]
    if conn[cell_0-1] != '1'  and conn[cell_1-1] != '1' :
        graph[cell_0].add(cell_1)
    path_list = ""
    for cell in range(1,N):
        if conn[cell-1] != '1' :
             path_conn_number = shortest_path(graph, 0, cell )
           if  path_conn_number != None :
               path_list += str(len(path_conn_number)-1) + ' '
           else :
               path_list += '-1' + ' '
        else :
           path_list += '-1' + ' '
    print(path_list)
```

Here is the problem detail .
https://a2oj.com/p?ID=481

Note : The contest has been ended but i want to know what is wrong ?!
what is the test case causes this error ?!.